# Conditional zonal statistics

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics, boolean

I have often used the Zonal Statistics plugin to calculate the mean pixel value of a raster. However, this time I have an additional Boolean (pixels are equal either to 1 or to 0) raster, which is overlapping with the other. I would like to calculate some kind of "conditional mean" of the former raster, i.e. the mean for those pixels which in the latter raster are equal to 0 and to 1. Can anyone suggest an approach? Is maybe R more appropriate that the the GRASS-GIS environment for doing so?

Answer (score 2):

In GRASS-GIS you can do it quite easily.

Assuming your binary raster with 1/0 value is named 'my_binary_raster', and the other you want to compute the mean value is named 'base_raster'.
Don't forget to define your Computational region correctly !

```
# Compute basic statistics on the base_raster, for each zones of the binary
g.region raster=base_raster
r.univar map=base_raster zones=my_binary_raster
```

It will return mean and a lot of other statistics.

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/g.region.html
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/r.univar.html